# text trasparent with three.js animated background and css class mess up the result

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have the text in the BUTTON TEXT trasparent to see the THREE.JS animation in background and IS WORKING if I don't insert the following css class as you can see in the first picture:

```
.center-mine{top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
```

[image]

but this way i have the text in the top left corner, while i needed that class to have the text in the center, as you can see in the second picture below
[image]
, but with that class, the BUTTON is no longer TRANSPARENT,

the WHOLE CSS and HTML is the following where i'm using come class from TAILWIND too.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*center-mine  class that makes everything not to work */
.center-mine{top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
.black {
background: black;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.font-exo{
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}
.font-space-mono{
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="absolute text-white text-center center-mine ">
    <h1 class="font-space-mono text-xl tracking-wider">AlexisWeber</h1>
    <p class="font-exo text-3xl ">AN EVERLASTING DESIRE FOR THE UNKNOWN & UNTOLD</p>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/4rc71c0" class=" inline-block border px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-space-mono lowercase mt-3 hover:bg-white hover:text-gray-800 hover:border-gray hover:uppercase " >Watch Works</a>


       <a class="black" href="#">button</a>


  </div>
</div>
```

i've spent quite some times but with no result for this problem.

I don't get why I can't have the button transparent also in the center.

(i'm a beginner)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute;` to center-mine class elsewhere left and top properties wont work;

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*center-mine  class that makes everything not to work */
.center-mine{top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);position:absolute}
.black {
background: black;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.font-exo{
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}
.font-space-mono{
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="absolute text-white text-center center-mine ">
    <h1 class="font-space-mono text-xl tracking-wider">AlexisWeber</h1>
    <p class="font-exo text-3xl ">AN EVERLASTING DESIRE FOR THE UNKNOWN & UNTOLD</p>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/4rc71c0" class=" inline-block border px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-space-mono lowercase mt-3 hover:bg-white hover:text-gray-800 hover:border-gray hover:uppercase " >Watch Works</a>


       <a class="black" href="#">button</a>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mmh, i did added position:absolute where you said but nothing changed

Comment: Outer element should be an element with relative position. Body itself is relative but if there is another parent element, make sure it is also relative. @AlessandroZerbini